# HTACCESS - Set environmental variable

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am currently trying to set an environmental variable on my nginx htaccess (from siteground), but I cannot read it in php via the following call:

```
<?php
    getenv('SOLT');
```

Here's my current .htaccess file (censored):

```
SetEnv PHPRC path/public_html/php.ini
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, private"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
SetEnv SOLT test
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve the issue?